# pandas find which half year a date belongs to

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas data frame with a `date` column. How can I add a column specifying which half year the date belongs to?

[image]

Comment: Please never post screenshots of data, always post the actual data \[[How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)\]. Because here **we need to know the dtype of your 'date' column: string, object, Python datetime, pandas pd.Timestamp...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert dates to datetimes and then use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with compare for less or equal:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

df['half year'] = np.where(df['date'].dt.month.le(6), 'H1', 'H2')
print (df)
        date half year
0 1993-09-09        H2
1 1993-09-11        H2
2 1994-01-23        H1
3 1993-03-18        H1
```

Solution without `numpy` with change mask for greater like `6`, add `1` and convert to strings:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

df['half year'] = 'H' + df['date'].dt.month.gt(6).add(1).astype(str)
print (df)
        date half year
0 1993-09-09        H2
1 1993-09-11        H2
2 1994-01-23        H1
3 1993-03-18        H1
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible without numpy?

Comment: @dInGd0nG - answer was edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your values as `DatetimeIndex` then use Pandas methods to chain transformations:

```
# Fixed by @MatBailie
df['half year'] = 'H' + pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.month.sub(1).floordiv(6).add(1).astype(str)
print(df)

# Output
          date half year
0   2023-01-01        H1
1   2023-02-01        H1
2   2023-03-01        H1
3   2023-04-01        H1
4   2023-05-01        H1
5   2023-06-01        H1
6   2023-07-01        H2
7   2023-08-01        H2
8   2023-09-01        H2
9   2023-10-01        H2
10  2023-11-01        H2
11  2023-12-01        H2
```

Minimal Working Example:

```
data = ['2023-01-01', '2023-02-01', '2023-03-01', '2023-04-01', 
        '2023-05-01', '2023-06-01', '2023-07-01', '2023-08-01', 
        '2023-09-01',  '2023-10-01', '2023-11-01', '2023-12-01']
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': data})
```

Comment: Months are 1 to 12, not 0 to 11, so you need `month-1`

Comment: @MatBailie. Thanks for pointing this out to me. I fixed my answer. It should be correct now.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `.apply` method.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['09-09-1993', '11-09-1993', '23-01-1994', '18-03-1993']})
>>>
>>> df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
>>> df
        date
0 1993-09-09
1 1993-09-11
2 1994-01-23
3 1993-03-18
>>>
>>> df['half year'] = df.date.dt.month.apply(lambda x: "H1" if x in range(0, 7) else "H2")
>>> df
        date half year
0 1993-09-09        H2
1 1993-09-11        H2
2 1994-01-23        H1
3 1993-03-18        H1
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `numpy`, a rather general solution that could easily be modified to get semesters as `'first'` or `'second'`:

0. build a `pandas.DataFrame` (not in the provided code)

(Code starts from here)*

1. convert the `'date'` column to datetime
2. extract month as a `pandas.Series` from `df['date']` using `pandas.Series.dt.month`
3. integer divide by 6 to get the semesters as a `pandas.Series` of `int` (counting from 0)
4. get the semester strings as a `pandas.Series` using `pandas.Series.map` with the semesters ints as indices on a semester names list
5. bundling (steps 2. to 4.) with `pandas.Categorical` to get categorical column (lower space, faster processing), this step is optional

[Code modified (2023-12-20) in response to error identified by @MatBailie]

```
>>> df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
>>> df['half year'] = pd.Categorical(((df['date'].dt.month - 1) // 6).map(lambda h:['H1','H2'][h]))
>>> df
        date half year
0 1993-09-09        H2
1 1993-09-11        H2
2 1994-01-23        H1
3 1993-03-18        H1
>>> df.dtypes
date         datetime64[ns]
half year          category
dtype: object
```

Comment: Month gives values from 1 to 12. So, you need `(month - 1) // 6`